# How can BeginInvoke with one delegate argument compile in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

The following website shows the signature of the function but none allow for a single parameter.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx

The following website shows the silverlight declaration that takes the Action type which seems to match what the sample program is doing.  However the sample program is not a silverlight but a WPF application.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190259(v=vs.95).aspx

I'm trying to understand how to read the documentation to verify my understanding of the sample program.  I can't figure out what specifically this program is linking against that would provide the capability.  Below is a function from the program which came from the book Windows Presentation Foundation 4.5 Cookbook.  The call matches the version of DispatcherInvoke that I see in the silverlight documentation which seems odd considering it is not a silverlight app, and the .net framework doesn't seem to provide that signature.  Somewhere other than within the silverlight documentation I should be able to find where that function signature is described right?

```
private void OnCalculate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            try {
                int first = int.Parse(_from.Text), last = int.Parse(_to.Text);
                _calcButton.IsEnabled = false;
                _cancelButton.IsEnabled = true;
                _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
                    int total = CountPrimes(first, last, _cts.Token);
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                        _result.Text = total < 0 ? "Cancelled!" : "Total Primes: " + total.ToString();
                        _cancelButton.IsEnabled = false;
                        _calcButton.IsEnabled = true;
                    }));
                });
            }
            catch(FormatException ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Reading further, the book does mention that WPF 4.5 provides more overloads.  Although that is slightly helpful, I still don't understand where that is described in the Microsoft documentation.  A follow-up question would be, how does WPF provide overloads to things that were originally defined in .Net?  I thought the Dispatcher class was just part of the .net framework threading namespace so I don't know what it means when someone writes that WPF provides more overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the overloads is `BeginInvoke(Delegate, Object[])`. Although this appears to require two arguments, when you look at the [docs for that method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see that it is actually defined as

```
public DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke(
    Delegate method,
    params object[] args
)
```

The second argument uses the params keyword, which means that any number of object arguments may be passed after the Delegate parameter. Zero object arguments is perfectly valid, and will result in the method receiving an empty array.

Comment: Are you sure?  The docs indicate that null can be passed but that isn't the same thing as passing nothing.  I'm thinking that somehow the WPF framework provides an extension to the method defined in .Net because there must be a declaration that takes only one argument.

Comment: Yes, that's how [params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) work: "You also can send no arguments. If you send no arguments, the length of the params list is zero."

Comment: Okay.  I see what you are saying.  It turns out that the project I am using is not using WPF4.5 anyway.  What the book says still might be true, but I'd have to check by setting up a visual studio 2015 project and see if there are more overloads.  The book still implies that is not the overload that it is talking about.  It seems to still be suggesting that there is a more specific overload with one param.